# while loop in python sql query

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hi i have try this query in php which is running fine and i have to do this same in python

```
   $select=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT A.entity_id AS entity_id ,A.email AS email,A.catquizid AS style_quiz_score ,A.catquizquesans AS style_quiz_answer,A.created_at AS date_joined,A.is_active AS is_active ,B.attribute_id AS attribute_id,B.value AS info FROM `customer_entity` AS A inner join  `customer_entity_varchar` AS B on A.entity_id=B.entity_id WHERE B.`attribute_id` IN  (1,2) limit 10",$conn);

    $arr=array();

    while($result= mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
        { 
            if(!isset($arr[$result['entity_id']]['lastname'])){
                $arr[$result['entity_id']]['firstname'] = $result['info'];
            }
            $arr[$result['entity_id']]['lastname'] = $result['info'];
            $arr[$result['entity_id']]["email"]=$result['email'];
            $arr[$result['entity_id']]["style_quiz_score"]=$result['style_quiz_score'];
            $arr[$result['entity_id']]["style_quiz_answer"]=$result['style_quiz_answer'];
            $arr[$result['entity_id']]["date_joined"]=$result['date_joined'];
            $arr[$result['entity_id']]["is_active"]=$result['is_active'];

            $arr[$result['entity_id']]["username"]=normalize_str($result['email']);
        }
```

and in python i have tried this

```
def customer_migrate(request):
    cursor = connections['migration'].cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT A.entity_id AS entity_id ,A.email AS email,A.catquizid AS style_quiz_score ,A.catquizquesans AS style_quiz_answer,A.created_at AS date_joined,A.is_active AS is_active ,B.attribute_id AS attribute_id,B.value AS info FROM customer_entity AS A inner join  customer_entity_varchar AS B on A.entity_id=B.entity_id WHERE B.attribute_id limit 4 ")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
```

how can i use the while loop in the python query ,

Comment: why was this question tagged with 'django'? are you looking for a solution for django too?

Comment: i am using django frame work with python

Comment: in that case, i suggest using django's models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/   it allows you to execute raw sql queries too:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 3):

Use fetchone() or just iterate through the cursor:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print row
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

or

```
for row in cursor:
    print row
```

Comment: the main problem i am facing is with alias names , i cannot fetch tha data like row['entity_id'] , because it doesn't return the dict names , i have read the docs how i get the data with dict names but it doesn't work for me . NOw what i want is the way i used the while loop in PHP can i used it in python

Comment: i have use this desc = cursor.description   and got the folowing       ('entity_id', 3, 2, 10, 10, 0, 0)('email', 253, 23, 765, 765, 0, 0)('style_quiz_score', 253, 5, 765, 765, 0, 0)('style_quiz_answer', 252, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0)('date_joined', 12, 19, 19, 19, 0, 0)('is_active', 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)('attribute_id', 2, 1, 5, 5, 0, 0)('info', 253, 7, 765, 765, 0, 0)   , i cant understand its meaning

Comment: @Rohit Are you using pyodbc? Since you are selecting with "AS" you should be able to do: `row.entitiy_id`

Also, the list order of the row is the same as the select statement, so you could use list indexes.

Comment: if i am using arr['a']=row[0][7] i got the 7th element of row array, how can i do this inside while loop

Comment: yes you are right but for one user there are 4 rows whose last element is different rest are the same so i have to access them like [0][7],[1][7]....so i want this in while loop , i know it might be confusing for you

Comment: you could do `cursor[0][7]` or do `rows = fetchall()`, iterate over the rows variable then use `row[0][7]` if I am understanding correctly.

However if you are using Django with this, you can simply create a model for this data, then use the objects manager to retrieve the results:

Comment: @RohitGoel Sry went over my 5 min of edits...


That should be `rows[0][7]`


If you have a Customer model linked to a CustomerVarchar model, you could simply do:



`Customer.objects.filter(CustomerVarchar__range=(1, 2))`

Comment: there is one more surprise for you sorry to forget to tell you about this , acctualy i am migrating the data from magento to pyhton ,thats why i am using raw query